# Are there books specifically on the subject of modulation?

Tags: theory, composition, modulation, books

Questions concerning smooth modulations, especially how to effect them, keep coming up in my own efforts at composition. Apart from Max Reger's little treatise (which in some ways is and in other ways isn't helpful), are there any other books specifically on this subject? Or at least a harmony text that delves into this subject extensively. To be clear, I don't need more information about pivot chords, etc., but rather on how to prepare the ground for my modulations in a smooth and convincing way, and on how best to confirm the new key.

Comment: Have you considered the horse's mouth? Pick some masterpieces and study the modulations yourself with regard to harmony, harmonic rhythm, motive, and so on. This isn't an answer to your question because I'm not naming books, but I'm convinced it's the best approach because the knowledge gained comes through your own consideration, and you learn more great music in the process. Once you start to notice trends, you could ask more specific questions here about their validity, for example.

Comment: Thanks! That's always sound advice, of course. But I simply need a bit more formalized guidance. (And I like to learn from books.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frank Shepard has a book on the subject: How To Modulate."
It's available on the internet: https://archive.org/details/howtomodulatesim00shep/page/n4

Comment: Thanks a million times over! Something like this is exactly what I was looking for.